# How to pass all loop value and pass to ajax?

Tags: ajax

Why it returns only the last number of my database? I wanted to return all value inside the `div`. Help me.

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
          url      : 'Test.php',
          method   : 'post', 
          data     : {id: id},
          success  : function(response)
          {
            var x = $.parseJSON(response);
            for (var a in b) 
            {
                 $('#allValue').html(b[a]);
            }
          }
      });
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query))
    {
        $result[] = array($row['ID_reservation']);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing

```
$("#element").html("TEST");
```

The HTML method removes any existing content and replaces it with "TEST".  If you want to append text you could first get the HTML value, but better yet:

```
var x = $.parseJSON(response);
var text = "";
for (var a in b) 
{
    text += b[a];
}

$('#allValue').html(text);
```